# Oracle PLSQL cursor nested select case

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, nested, case

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I have two tables one with a list of id numbers to lookup and the other table with the nodes and responses from the nodes.  I'm checking to see if a response is registered in the one table with a matching id number, the id numbers exist in both tables but a response either has records or does not. the expected output is simple:

```
id_num         rec_exists
______         __________
000123         Y
000124         N
...
```

Here is my code:

```
set serveroutput ON 
DECLARE 
CURSOR c1 IS 
  SELECT id_num 
  FROM   pcnodes; 
i          NUMBER := 0; 
rec_exists CHAR(20); 
b          CHAR(20); 
BEGIN 
FOR e_rec IN c1 LOOP 
    i := i + 1; 

    SELECT CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                          FROM   computer_node a, 
                                 node_response b 
                          WHERE  id_num IN ( e_rec ))
           THEN 'Y' 
           ELSE 'N' 
           END AS rec_exists 
    FROM   dual; 

    dbms_output.Put_line(i 
                         ||Chr(20) 
                         ||e_rec.id_num 
                         ||Chr(20) 
                         ||rec_exists); 
END LOOP;
```

END;

Comment: Please post also error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

First: You should save your case result into variable, missing INTO

```
SELECT CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                          FROM   computer_node a, 
                                 node_response b 
                          WHERE  id_num IN ( e_rec ))
           THEN 'Y' 
           ELSE 'N' 
           END AS rec_exists 
           INTO rec_exists
    FROM   dual;
```

Second: you are using two tables in your query and only one condition, not sure that was intended. If both tables have `id_num` column, then you should add that to your condition

```
SELECT *
FROM computer_node a, 
     node_response b 
WHERE a.id_num = e_rec
  AND b.id_num = a.id_num
```

Or something like that, depending on your tables

But you can do all this in single query, no need for cursor loop and then another query inside

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I agree, it's not my querry, just c/p of authors. If he likes it that way, who am I to judge :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will give your result without cursor:

```
select nvl(a.id_num, b.id_num) as id, nvl2(p.id_num,'Y','N') 
  from node_response b 
  full outer join computer_node a on (a.id_num = b.id_num) 
  left outer join pcnodes p on (p.id_num = nvl(a.id_num, b.id_num));
```

`FROM   computer_node a, node_response b` make no sense this is cross join. If your going to check if id exists in at least one of those tables use `full join` as above. If `id_num` is only in one of those tables use single table like below:

```
select b.id_num, nvl2(p.id_num,'Y','N') 
      from node_response b 
      left outer join pcnodes p on (p.id_num = b.id_num;
```